# How can $1/f(z)$ have a zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, laurent-series, analytic-functions, singularity

On page 173 of Complex Analysis, Gamelin, the author states the following theorem:

> Let $z_0$ be an isolated singularity of $f(z)$. Then $z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$ of order $N$ if and only if $1/f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ and has a zero of order $N$.

How can $1/f(z)$ have a zero, if $1/f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$?

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{f(z)} \neq 0$ for all z? I'm thinking of a function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, which would have $\frac{1}{f(z)} = z$, which has a zero at $0$

Comment: If $f(z)=2/z^2$ then $1/f(z)=z^2/2$.  He assumes you filled in the gap at $z=0$.  Now $1/f(z)$ has a zero order $2$, so $f(z)$ has a pole of order $2$

Comment: what do you try?

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks, I didn't think to fill in the gap. So, $1/f(z)$ has a zero at $z_0$ if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} 1/f(z) = 0$?

Comment: It also has to be analytic there, as they say in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $z_0$ is the n-th order pole, then $f(z)$ has the Laurent series at the neighborhood of $z_0$, which is

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^k$$

where $\color{red}{a_{-n}\neq0}$, hence we have

$$\frac1{f(z)}=\frac1{\displaystyle\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k}=\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^{k+n}}$$

Let $m=k+n$

$$\frac1{f(z)}=\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m-n} (z-z_0)^{m}}=\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{a_{-n}+\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m-n} (z-z_0)^{m}}$$

Since $\color{red}{a_{-n}\neq0}$, the denominator is analytic and non-vanish at $z=z_0$, therefore, $z_0$ is the n-th order zero of $1/f(z)$.